# Java how to start a game turn class for stored turn data

Tags: java, class, dice

I'm making a dice game and need to know how I might set up a class that stores the dice roll numbers from the previous turn such that an if statement can display something. I.E. if computerDie == 1 && userDie == 4 occurs twice in a row something happens. Any suggestions?

```
public static void main( String [] args ){
    Random random = new Random();
    int totalNumberOfTurns = 1;
    int computerDie;
    int userDie;
    int computerScore = 0;
    int userScore = 0;


    for( int turn = 1; turn <= totalNumberOfTurns; turn++ ) {
        computerDie = random.nextInt( 6 ) + 1;
        userDie = random.nextInt( 6 ) + 1;

        if () {
}
}
}
```

Comment: I would use an arraylist inside the computer object and another one in a user object. then everytime they roll you add the value to the arraylist and calling something like rollHistory.get(rollHistory.size - 1) will be the most recent roll and rollHistory.get(rollHistory.size - 2) will the be the one before it assuming you have had more than 1 dice roll

Answer (score 1):

You could use an [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) and save each roll for each player if you need to use them later.

Or if you don't care to use them later, you can have 2 auxiliar variables like `lastUserDie` and `lastComputerDie` which are updated after you check if they're the same.

In this example I used a random between 1-3 to make it more probable to get the same roll, just change it to 6 again

```
import java.util.Random;

public class SaveLastDiceRoll {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random random = new Random();

        int totalNumberOfTurns = 10;

        int computerDie = 0;
        int userDie = 0;
        int computerScore = 0;
        int userScore = 0;
        int lastUserDie = 0;
        int lastComputerDie = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < totalNumberOfTurns; i++) {
            computerDie = random.nextInt(3) + 1;
            userDie = random.nextInt(3) + 1;
            System.out.println("UserRoll: " + userDie);
            System.out.println("ComputerRoll: " + computerDie);
            System.out.println("------------");
            if (sameRoll(lastUserDie, userDie, lastComputerDie, computerDie)) {
                System.out.println("GAME OVER, SAME ROLL TWICE");
                break;
            }
            lastComputerDie = computerDie;
            lastUserDie = userDie;
        }
    }

    public static boolean sameRoll(int lastUserDie, int currentUserDie, int lastComputerDie, int currentComputerDie) {
        if (lastUserDie == currentUserDie && lastComputerDie == currentComputerDie) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Some sample outputs:

```
UserRoll: 1
ComputerRoll: 1
------------
UserRoll: 1
ComputerRoll: 1
------------
GAME OVER, SAME ROLL TWICE
```

And:

```
UserRoll: 3
ComputerRoll: 1
------------
UserRoll: 2
ComputerRoll: 3
------------
UserRoll: 2
ComputerRoll: 2
------------
UserRoll: 2
ComputerRoll: 1
------------
UserRoll: 2
ComputerRoll: 1
------------
GAME OVER, SAME ROLL TWICE
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need an OOP overhaul.

For object oriented programming, you want to encapsulate information and related functionality in a reusable fashion. For your scenario, you have the user and the computer, but both of those sets of information can be thought of as a player (and associated information). That suggests creating a `Player` class to store both the score and the rolls that have been made for that player:

```
public class Player {
    private int score;
    private List<Integer> diceRolls;
}
```

From there, we add methods to class `Player` that allow for the mutation and retrieval of the stored information.

```
public class Player {
    private int score;
    // Rolls are stored in chronological order. Last element is most recent.
    private List<Integer> diceRolls;

    public Player() {
        score = 0;
        diceRolls = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    }

    public int getScore() {
        return score;
    }

    public int addRoll(int roll) {
        diceRolls.add(roll);
    }

    public int getMostRecentRoll() {
        return diceRolls.get(diceRolls.size() - 1);
    }

    public boolean mostRecentTwoRollsMatch() {
        return diceRolls.size() >= 2 && 
            diceRolls.get(diceRolls.size() - 1).equals(diceRolls.get(diceRolls.size() - 2));

    public List<Integer> getAllRolls() {
        return new ArrayList<>(diceRolls); // copied for safety
    }
}
```

From there, coding your logic in the `main` method becomes much simpler and easier to understand.

```
public static void main( String [] args ){
    Random random = new Random();
    int totalNumberOfTurns = 10;
    Player user = new Player();
    Player computer = new Player();

    for(int turn = 0; turn < totalNumberOfTurns; turn++ ) {
       user.addRoll(random.nextInt(6) + 1);
       computer.addRoll(random.nextInt(6) + 1);

       if (user.mostRecentTwoRollsMatch()) {
           System.out.println("User rolled " + user.getMostRecentRoll() + " twice!");
       }

       // etc etc...
    }
}
```